# resizeWindow not working for opencv 2.4.8 in osx 10.9

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, opencv, user-interface

I am using a simple c++ program in mac osx 10.9, using opencv 2.4.8 which has been compiled with QT support and OPENGL support. Here is the relevant portion of my cmake config for building opencv 2.4.8

```
GUI: 
--     QT 4.x:                      YES (ver 4.8.6 EDITION = OpenSource)
--     QT OpenGL support:           YES (/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.5/lib/QtOpenGL.framework)
--     OpenGL support:              YES (/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework)
```

Here is a simple GUI program,

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {    namedWindow("my-win", WINDOW_OPENGL);
    int desiredWindowWidth = 800, desiredWindowHeight =600;
    resizeWindow("my-win", desiredWindowWidth, desiredWindowHeight);
    cv::VideoCapture capture(0);
    for(;;) {
        Mat view;
        if( capture.isOpened() )
        {
            capture >> view;
        }
        imshow("my-win", view);
        char key = (char)waitKey(30);
        if( key == 's') {
            unsigned char* pixels = new unsigned char [ 3 * desiredWindowWidth * desiredWindowHeight];
            glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
            glReadPixels(0, 0, desiredWindowWidth, desiredWindowHeight, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
            Mat savedImage(desiredWindowHeight, desiredWindowWidth, CV_8UC3, pixels);
            cv::flip(savedImage, savedImage, 0);
            imwrite("./foo.jpg", savedImage);
        }
    }
}
```

Result : I get a window with the current video camera image as output. So far so good.
But the window that I get is small compared to what I had asked for (800 x 600) possibly a 400 x 300 window. Further, if I give any other proportional window size parameters, (eg: 1200 x 900), I still get the same sized window. Look like the "resizeWindow" is not functioning properly.

There is no way to check the size of the window created. What I did was to save the window as an image, I get a black 800 x 600 image with the window content appearing in one corner as a 400x300 part.

Comment: Is that a retina display? Could be some mix-up related to that. Also, your config mentions both Qt 4.8.5 and Qt 4.8.6. That looks strange.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that, I was indeed using openGL 2.1 as demonstrated by the following glxinfo output.

```
    glxinfo | grep OpenGL
    OpenGL vendor string: Intel Inc.
    OpenGL renderer string: Intel Iris Pro OpenGL Engine
    OpenGL version string: 2.1 INTEL-8.20.26
    OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
    OpenGL extensions:
```

I rewrote my application by including glew and gflw3 and forced a 3.2 version of OpenGL.
Now I am able to control the size of the window.

```
    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        GLFWwindow* window;
        const GLubyte * strGLVersion;
        if (!glfwInit())
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        //ask for OpenGL 3.2
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);


        window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "check-opengl", NULL, NULL);
        if (!window) {
            glfwTerminate();
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

        //more accommodating glew
        glewExperimental = true;

        if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
            glfwTerminate();
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        //v-sync off
        glfwSwapInterval(0);
        //print version
        strGLVersion = glGetString(GL_VERSION);
        cout << "GL_VERSION:" << strGLVersion << endl;
        const GLubyte * strGLShadingLanguageVersion = glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION);
        cout << "GL_VERSION:" << strGLShadingLanguageVersion << endl;

        VideoCapture cap(0);
        if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
            return -1;


        Mat image;
        cap >> image;
        const string win_name("kgeorge-ar");
        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

            cap >> image;

            //-----------8<------ snip -------8<------------
            //code for converting image to opengl texture
            //and rendering it to a quad is omited
            //-----------8<------ snip -------8<------------

            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            glfwPollEvents();
        }

        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        return 0;
    }
```